# How to isolate $x$ in the inequality $3^{x+2}<5^{x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For example,

\begin{align}
0.4^x &\gt 0.9 \\
\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^x &\gt \left(\frac{9}{10}\right) \\
\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^x &\gt \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{\log_{2/5} \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)} \\
\text{So,}\qquad x &\gt \log_{2/5}\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)
\end{align}

Am I correct?

May I ask how to solve this type of inequality?

$$3^{x+2} \lt 5^{x-1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*One approach:*

$\ln$ is a strictly increasing function, i.e., $\ln a < \ln b$ iff $a < b$.

Thus $3^{x + 2} < 5^{x-1}$ iff

$$(x+2)\ln 3 < (x-1)\ln 5$$

iff

$$(\ln 3 - \ln 5)x < -\ln 5 - 2\ln 3$$

iff

$$(\ln 5 - \ln 3)x > \ln 5 + \ln 9 = \ln 45$$

iff

$$x > \frac{\ln 45}{\ln 5 - \ln 3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is correct.

To solve $3^{x+2}=3^x3^2<5^{x-1}=5^x5^{-1}$ you can rearrange this equation into a form $(\frac{3}{5})^x<\frac{1}{45}$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,

$$ab^{cx+d}<AB^{Cx+D}$$
becomes, after taking the logarithm

$$\log(a)+\log(b)(cx+d)<\log(A)+\log(B)(Cx+D),$$

then

$$\log(a)-log(A)+\log(b)d-\log(B)D<(\log(B)C-\log(b)c)x$$
and, if $\log(B)C-\log(b)c>0$,

$$\frac{\log(a)-\log(A)+\log(b)d-\log(B)D}{\log(B)C-\log(b)c}<x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $$f(x)=3^{x+2}-5^{x-1}$$ and control the $lim_{x \to-\infty} f(x)$ and $lim_{x \to-\infty} f(x)$ then control that $f'(x)<0$ for every value of $x$